# how to convert Excel row to string value in Java?

Tags: java, excel, string, apache-poi, row

Is there a direct built-in function in Java POI to convert an Excel row to string?
I have tried "row.toString()" but it returned the memory location of the row.

Comment: try reading cell by cell and then append it to string

Comment: @SpringLearner I am doing that already and it works .. but I'd like to optimize my solution by avoiding nested loop.

Comment: @andrew Why? What's wrong with the nested loop? Do you have any performance issues with it?

Comment: What do you expect to be "the string value of a row in Excel"? A Excel row contains multiple cells, each cell having their own value and not all of those cell values must be strings.

Answer (score 2):

All the code you need to do this is given in the [Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/), specifically [iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) and [getting the cell contents](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents). Reading the documentation often helps!

Assuming you want to do something simple like join all the cells together with commas (note - not a good way to generate a CSV as you also need to escape things!) you'd do something like this:

```
// Load the file, get the first sheet
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xls"));
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

// To turn numeric and date cells into friendly formatted strings
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

// Process every row
for (Row row : sheet) {
   StringBuffer text = new Stringbuffer();
   // Turn each cell into a string, and append
   for (Cell : row) {
      if (! text.isEmpty()) { text.append(", "); }
      text.append(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
   }

   // TODO Do something useful with the string
   String rowAsText = text.toString();
}

// Tidy up
wb.close();
```

Comment: Aha! Zackly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dont iterate through all Cells/Lines, just pick your certain Cell by following:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 8;   
// open your File
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
// Get your excel sheet nr. 1
XSSFSheet sheet = Workbook.getSheetAt(0);
// get your Row from Y cordinate
Row yourRow = sheet.getRow(y);
// get your Cell from X cordinate
Cell yourCell = cell = yourRow.getCell(x);
// be sure that the pointingCell is an String or else it will catch Exception.
String cellString = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over Cells,

```
       Row row = (Row) rows.next();
        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

     while (cells.hasNext()) {
      Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next();
...
}
```

And for retrieve a string of a cell you can use :

```
cell.getStringCellValue()
```

Comment: Only if the cell really contains a string, and not something like a formatted number or formatted date....

Comment: Of course yes, It's also possible to use : **cell.getCellType()**  to retrieve the value type and adapt your code logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
     XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("path")));

        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
          while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
               Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType()) 
                {                  
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        double a = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        String val = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                 }
            }
```

Comment: This will fail for non-string cells, eg formatted numbers

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by also adding an explanation. Just a code sample alone is not helpful, and could lead people to using it in inappropriate circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Files class in java. It has methods for e.g

`Files.lines(Path path)`

that takes in a path and returns a Stream. With a stream you can split the rows and apply your methods. You can take a look at its API for its other methods whichever may be more applicable.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: Well good luck while trying this method on an `Excel` file. An `Excel` is either a binary file (`*.xls`) or an `ZIP` archive containing multiple `XML` files in a directory structure (`*.xlsx`), but never a file which can be interpreted as rows of text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the java8 `foreach` to get maybe a more convenient code:

```
try (
    InputStream inputStream = RowToString.class.getResourceAsStream("excel.xlsx");
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
) {
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    sheet.forEach(row -> {
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("|");
        row.forEach(cell -> joiner.add(cell.toString()));
        rows.add(joiner.toString());
    });

    rows.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The `StringJoiner` is a good choice to concatenate the values. For get the cell values, the `toString` works fine. The `toString` will get the proper value of any cell type. The only problem is that the `toString` won't resolve a formula, it will get the formula  itself. But you can adapt the code for your own necessity.